# Azure Function PDF Generation

Tags: python, c#, azure, azure-functions, pdf-generation

Has anyone successfully deployed an Azure Function that generates a pdf with graphics? I've written some python functions (with wkhtmltopdf) that work locally, but do not work when deployed. I've written a few in C# since there appears to be a greater variety of libraries/wrappers to utilize.

I have also tried the 3 tiers of azure functions as well (Consumption, Basic and Premium). And of course I'm trying to avoid having to use any licensed products.

Comment: Could you please provide the error message and function code?

Comment: The problem isn't the code, it's in how the code is deployed.

Comment: Could you please provide the error messsage?